# Why am I getting the error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’)?

Tags: c++, queue, nodes

I get this error when I try to compile either popRight or popLeft. Why? Here are the codes.

Dequeue class

```
  #include "node.h"
template <class T>
class Dequeue
{
    public:
        void pushLeft(T data);
        void popLeft();
        T left();
        void pushRight(T data);
        void popRight();
        T right();
        bool empty();
    private:
        int length;
};

template<typename T>
bool Dequeue<T>::empty()
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

template<typename T>
void Dequeue<T>::pushLeft(T data)
   {
        if (empty() == true)
        {
            left->setData(data);
            right->setData(data);
        }
        else if (left->getData() == right->getData())
        {
            left->setData(data);
        }
        else
        {
            node<T> *aux = new node<T>;
            aux->setData(data);
            left->setPrevious(aux);
            aux->setNext(left);
            left = aux;
        }
        length++;

    }

template<typename T>
  void Dequeue<T>::pushRight(T data)
   {
        if (empty() == true)
        {
            right->setData(data);
            left->setData(data);
        }
        else if (right->getData() == left->getData())
        {
            right->setData(data);
        }
        else
        {
            node<T> *aux = new node<T>;
            aux->setData(data);
            right->setPrevious(aux);
            aux->setNext(right);
            right = aux;
        }
        length++;
    }

template<typename T>
 void Dequeue<T>::popLeft()
    {
        node<T> *node = left->getNext();
        node->setPrevious(NULL);
        left = node;
    }

template<typename T>
 void Dequeue<T>::popRight()
 {
        node<T> *node = right->getPrevious();
        node->setNext(NULL);
        right = node;
  }
```

Node Class

```
 template <class T>
class node
{
    public:
        node(T data);
        node(T data, node<T>* next);
        T getData();
        node<T>* getNext();
        void setData(T data);
        void setNext(node<T>* next);
        void setPrevious(node<T>* previous);
    private:
        T data;
        node<T> *next;
        node<T> *previous;
        node<T> *left;
        node<T> *right;
};

template <typename T>
node<T>::node(T data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = NULL;
    this->previous = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>::node(T data, node<T>* next)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->next = next;
    this->previous = previous;
}

template <typename T>
T node<T>::getData()
{
    return this->data;
}

template <typename T>
node<T>* node<T>::getNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T>::setData(T data)
{
    this->data=data;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T>::setNext(node<T>* next)
{
    this->next = next;
}

template <typename T>
void node<T>::setPrevious(node<T>* previous)
{
    this->previous = previous;
}
```

Ive been trying to solve this problem for like an hour but I just can't, can anyone help?

Comment: What error exactly? Which line?

Comment: Your `left` and `right` are functions. By the way, putting at least a comment on the line with the error would've been appreciated.

Comment: getting it in this line:   

node<T> *node = right->getPrevious();

Also getting same error in

right = node;

Comment: `T left();` and `T right();` mean that these are supposed to be member functions, not member variables. I suspect that's not what you meant to do, since you never defined the functions.

Comment: Off topic: Your lack of [Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) may bite you in unexpected and painful ways.

Answer (score 3):

You declared `left` and `right` as functions. But it's clear from the way you use them in the rest of the code that they should be variables.

```
class Dequeue
{
    public:
        void pushLeft(T data);
        void popLeft();
        T left;
        void pushRight(T data);
        void popRight();
        T right;
        bool empty();
    private:
        int length;
};
```